# Hot deployed custom Mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I made a custom mediator. I want to add a Home> Manage> ESB Artifacts> Add
How to do it?

when I add a jar he does not see my classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the server..We dont recommend hot deployments..

Answer (score 1):

made under this instruction and it worked
http://achala11.blogspot.ru/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html